# Matrix row/column manipulation in matlab

Tags: matlab, networking, matrix

I have got the following function for spreading out the number of 1's in a matrix and if there are rows with all 0's or all 1's then that particular row has to be deleted

```
function ReducedMatrix = ReduceMatrix(result)
D1 = sum(result(:));
NumberOfOnes = floor(D1*0.3);
NewMatrix = zeros(size(result));
NewMatrix(randi(numel(NewMatrix),1,NumberOfOnes)) = 1;
ReducedMatrix = NewMatrix;
while numel(ReducedMatrix)/numel(NewMatrix) > 0.2
IndexOfFullRows = find(all(ReducedMatrix));
if isempty(IndexOfFullRows)

    break
end
ReducedMatrix(:,IndexOfFullRows(1)) = [];

end
end
```

The input of the function and output are as follows

```
 result =

 0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
 1     1     1     1     1     0     1     0     1     1
 1     1     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
 1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0
 1     1     1     1     1     1     0     1     0     1
 1     0     1     1     1     1     1     0     1     1
 1     1     1     1     0     1     1     1     0     1
 1     0     1     1     1     0     1     1     1     1
 1     1     1     1     0     1     0     1     1     1
 1     1     1     0     1     1     1     1     1     1


 ReducedMatrix =

 0     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
 0     1     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0
 1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     1     0     0     1     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0
 0     1     0     0     0     0     1     0     1     1
 1     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     1
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 1     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     1


row_sum =

 3
 2
 3
 2
 1
 4
 2
 2
 0
 3


col_sum =

 3     4     4     1     0     0     3     2     2     3
```

Now if there exists a row or column with the row_sum/col_sum equal to either 0 or 1 then then the corresponding row has to be deleted.
For Example. Row-R4,R9 and Col-C4,C5,C6 have row_sum and col_sum as either 1,0. So adding them up R4,R9,C4,C5,C6 = 5 rows have to be eliminated from the matrix so my reduced matrix should be of the size 5x5. Please note column should not be eliminated and instead of removing columns having 0 and 1, the corresponding rows can be removed. Similarly this function has to run for larger matrices with the same constraints. I tried doing the above function however i do not possess enough skills to achieve my desired results, Any help is much appreciated

Comment: So what happens if removing a row now changes the column sums and makes it so you now have to delete another column?

Comment: i have made a constrained in the function that not more than 30% of the rows can be reduced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a number of potential problems and possible simplifications to your code.

For one thing, the way you construct the original matrix, `NewMatrix(randi(numel(NewMatrix),1,NumberOfOnes)) = 1;` may not behave the way you would expect. `randi` does not guarantee that the same index will not appear multiple times in the output, so your new matrix may have fewer ones than the original. To solve this, shuffle the elements using [`randperm`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html):

```
ReducedMatrix = [ones(1, NumberOfOnes), zeros(1, numel(result) - NumberOfOnes)];
ReducedMatrix = ReducedMatrix(randperm(numel(ReducedMatrix)));
ReducedMatrix = reshape(ReducedMatrix, size(result));
```

Secondly, you do not need to construct the new matrix as `NewMatrix` and then reassign it with `ReducedMatrix = NewMatrix;`. Just do `ReducedMatrix = zeros(size(result));` and skip the reassignment. For the `while` loop condition, where `NewMatrix` appears to be "used", remember that `numel(NewMatrix) == numel(result)`.

If you are not removing homogeneous columns, only rows, you do not need a loop to do the removal:

```
rowSum = sum(ReducedMatrix, 2);
rowMask = (rowSum == size(ReducedMatrix, 2) | rowSum == 0);
ReducedMatrix(rowMask, :) = [];
```

Your original code seems to swap the row and column indices when removing the rows. It also did not handle the case of all zeros. If you want to remove not more than 30% of rows, you can do something like this before the removal:

```
rowMask = find(rowMask); % Convert to indices
rowMask = rowMask(1:min(numel(rowMask), round(0.3 * size(ReducedMatrix, 2))));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer while i try out your solution how do i construct my original matrix without randi

Comment: @CJs Updated answer.

Comment: I get the following error - Operands to the || and && operators must be convertible to logical
scalar values.

Error in ReduceMatrix1 (line 19)
rowMask = (rowSum == size(ReducedMatrix, 2) || rowSum == 0);

Comment: Fixed typo, should have been a single pipe.

Comment: I am getting an empty matrix,i did not use any loop as suggested by you. This is what i did
`ReducedMatrix = [ones(1, NumberOfOnes), zeros(1, numel(result) - NumberOfOnes)];
ReducedMatrix = ReducedMatrix(randperm(numel(ReducedMatrix)));
ReducedMatrix = reshape(ReducedMatrix, size(result));
ReducedMatrix = zeros(size(result));
rowSum = sum(ReducedMatrix, 2);
rowMask = (rowSum == size(ReducedMatrix, 2) | rowSum == 0);
ReducedMatrix(rowMask, :) = [];
rowMask = find(rowMask); % Convert to indices
rowMask = rowMask(1:min(numel(rowMask), round(0.3 * size(ReducedMatrix, 2))));
end`

Comment: Why do you have this: `ReducedMatrix = zeros(size(result));` right after you construct the correct matrix? That sets all the elements of the output to zero, and the loop then correctly removes everything.

Comment: Also, you should look into the MATLAB debugger. It is a very convenient way to step through your code in a controlled manner and look at your workspace as you make changes to it in each line of code.

Comment: @CJs. Any particular reason for un-selecting this answer?

Comment: sorry about that